# After orderBy selectMany ensures the order of the elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object that has a an another object as property and this second objetc has a list as another propery. Something like that:

```
MyObjetA
{
    MyObjectB PropertyOnA;
    DateTime MyDate;
}

MyObjectB
{
    List<MyObjectC> PorperyonB;
}
```

I have a list of MyObjectA that I want to order by date, and from this, I want to set values in MyObjectC property in order, first the elements of the first MyObjectA ordered by date. So I was thinking something like that:

```
List<MyObjectA> myListObjectA = new List<MyObjectA>();
List<MyObjectC> myLstObjectC = miListObjectA.OrderBy(x=> x.MyDate).SelectMany(x=> x.PropertOnA).SelectMany(y=> y.ProperyOnB).ToList();
```

But I am not sure if SelectMany ensures that the elements are ordered or not.

The documentation says: "Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.". But it doesn't say anything about the order. I guess that it will project from first element to last in the myListObjectA ordered, but really I am not sure about this.

Comment: Use OrderBy after ToList, is it solves your problem?

Comment: The order of the original collection will be maintained, but depending on what the effects of flattening `PropertOnA` and `PropertOnB` does, that order might not be apparent in the final list.

Comment: What i need is that the properties ObjectC of the first object ObjectA are processed before the properties of the second ObjectA. But the order of the PropertyC inside a ObjectA no matter.